# android studio tab layout icon size

Tags: android, tabs, android-tablayout

I use TabLayout for tabs, but the icon is too small in the tab. How to fit the icon in the tab?

[image]

Comment: I'm using a 96x96 px icon - but it doesn't fit to the tab size.

Comment: Is it custom? can you post your xml?